# string array of varying length

Tags: c

Im writing a C code to read a file line by line which contains alphabets, CR,LF,'\0'. Below is my attached code sample. I want to store only alphabets from each line to an array such that the numbers of rows in the array equals no of lines in the file and column should be of varying length(depends on the number of character in i-th line).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *buffer[100];
    char temp[128];
    int c,i=0,j=0;
    int pos=0;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("input", "r");
    if (file) {
        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF){
            if ((c>=65 && c<=90) || (c>=97 && c<=122))
                temp[pos++]=c;
            else if(pos>1) {
                temp[pos]='\0';
                buffer[i]=temp;
                printf ("%s\n",temp);
                i++;
                pos=0;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    while (j<i){
        printf("%s\n",buffer[j]);
        j++;
    }
}
```

If i run my above code, all my buffer[j] contains same string.
Can anyone help me out in figuring what was wrong in the code.

Comment: A **debugger** would eagerly step up to the task if you asked it *real nice*. Apart from that, ask yourself "What am I storing in that pointer array each time I advance to a new string? Is it the same buffer address (temp) over and over?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buffer[]` is an array of *pointers*, in your `while` loop you are pointing each of them to your array `temp[]`

```
buffer[i]=temp; // assign the address of temp to buffer[i]
```

Then you're changing the *content* of your `temp[]` array, but the address is always the same.

If you want to *store* the data from `temp` into each position in `buffer[]` you need to allocate memory and copy the data over there. More like:

```
buffer[i]=malloc(strlen(temp) + 1);
strcpy(buffer[i], temp);
```

Comment: +1 Or `buffer[i] = strdup(temp)` if you're feeling particularly POSIX-ish that morning =P. Nice answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig Even if you are feeling POSIX-ish, stick to standard C. There is no reason to ever use strdup anywhere.

Comment: @Lundin I'll keep that in mind. Someone must have some pull, because it wasn't part of the POSIX standard until POSIX.1-2001.